# Meta's SAM model: can extract semantic embedding vector?

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I'm interested in finding an embedding vector for each segment found by the Facebook/Meta Segment Anything model (for classification and tracking of segments).

Can `SamPredictor.features` (the output of `model.image_encoder(input_image)`) be used for this? Its not clear to me how to interpret this data. I see its a `1x256x64x64` tensor - does the 256 corresponds to 0..255 possible segments, and can the `64x64` component be flattened and sensibly treated as a point in an embedding space?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any updates oh this topic? thanks